# JPA query in appegine datastore not working

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, persistence

I am trying to make a query to work, but with no luck. I am developing on AppEngine, using JPA for data access.
When I set the query string as:

```
"SELECT m FROM ModelLocationJPA m WHERE  m.latitude BETWEEN :lowerLatitude AND  :higherLatitude"
```

it works, and also :

```
  "SELECT m FROM ModelLocationJPA m WHERE  m.longitude BETWEEN :lowerLongitude AND :higherLongitude"
```

works. So, I guess that is because I messed something with the multiple "AND"'s, but I can't figure out what.

I am trying to make the following work but I get the error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument

```
EntityManager em = null;
    List<ModelLocationJPA> dbModelLocations = null;
    ArrayList<ModelLocation> modelLocations = new ArrayList<ModelLocation>();
    String aQuery = "SELECT m FROM ModelLocationJPA m WHERE  ( (m.latitude BETWEEN :lowerLatitude AND  :higherLatitude) AND ( m.longitude BETWEEN :lowerLongitude AND :higherLongitude ))";




    try {
         em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
            Query query = em.createQuery(aQuery);
            query.setParameter("lowerLatitude",box.getMinLatitude());
            query.setParameter("higherLatitude",box.getMaxLatitude());
            query.setParameter("lowerLongitude",box.getMinLongitude());
            query.setParameter("higherLongitude",box.getMaxLongitude());

                 dbModelLocations = query.getResultList();

        } finally {
        em.close();
        }
```

If someone could please tell me what is wrong, it would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries):

> A query may only use inequality filters (<, <=, >=, >, !=) on one
>   property across all of its filters.

Comment: Thank you. But, how can I solve my problem to filter on multiple proprieties the result? In my example, I would like to get the values with the latitude between maxLat and minLat and the longitude between maxLong and minLong.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe filter only on the latitude in the query, and then filter the rest in Java. Frankly, I find the DataStore so limited that it's not usable for most serious applications.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that in Java, but I guess that for a lot of values in the Datastore it will take more CPU cycles, so it will cost more. :( There has to be a solution for this...

Comment: @Berry Well there is a solution for that, but maybe not in GAE.. there are some limitations and you have to live with them or do it somewhere else.. Read the limitations carefully before deciding to build the whole thing on a specific platform.. there are no spatial queries in GAE.. but databases like MongoDB have them..

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to filter in java the rest, and I will see how it goes. I have accepted the answer.